# wxWidgets toolbar text alignment

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, toolbar

I am trying to add static text to my wxWidgets toolbar, but I can't figure out how to horizontally align it.

The code I am using is:

```
wxToolBar *m_toolbar;
wxStaticText *txt;

m_toolbar = CreateToolBar();
m_toolbar->SetToolBitmapSize( wxSize( 24, 24 ) );

txt = new wxStaticText( m_toolbar
                      , wxID_ANY
                      , "Sample Text"
                      , wxDefaultPosition
                      , wxDefaultSize
                      , wxALIGN_CENTRE );


m_toolbar->AddControl(txt);
```

I have seen a few posts about creating a custom version of wxStaticText::DoGetBestSize() but that hasn't helped either.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "horizontally aligning" it? Align it how? To the left, centre, right?

Comment: Align the text centre (horizontal) within a toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

Since 2.9.1 there is [wxToolBar::AddStretchableSpace()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_tool_bar.html#adb30df5ae52f2fabc974d0dd1376f5cd).
Call that before and after adding `txt`.